# Remove odd lines in a text file

Tags: linux, text, sed, awk, dropbox

File:

```
/home/USER/DIR/a
http://www.here.is.a.hyper.link.net/
/home/USER/DIR/b
http://www.here.is.another.hyper.link.net/
```

Need to remove all the odd lines in this file (`PUBLIC-DIRECTORY-LIST`)? Its for my batch script which can be found below (dropbox batch puburl creator):

```
for PATH in `cat LIST`
do
echo $PATH
dropbox puburl $PATH
done > PUBLIC-DIRECTORY-LIST
```

Do I just append the command to prune `PUBLIC-DIRECTORY-LIST` at the end of the script?

Comment: I'm still very knew to batch scripting - my first ever script XD.

Comment: don't use for loop with cat like that...because you will spaces problem later. use a while read loop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# awk 'NR%2==0' file
http://www.here.is.a.hyper.link.net/
http://www.here.is.another.hyper.link.net/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use awk for it, but that's just me:

```
awk '{if(i++%2)print}' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is the `sed` expression:

```
sed -e '1d;n;d' file
```

It is exactly as [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/unix/sed/print_every_other_line.html) except with an extra `1d` command, this deletes the first line and so prints the odd lines instead of the even ones.